# what does the 'debug mode' on Services actually do?

Tags: services

Each Services endpoint has an option for 'debug mode'.

What does this actually do?

Comment: It is used for testing more information here. http://drupal.org/node/790416. Also, it enables the logs in the service so you can in see reports the logs.

Comment: I'd read that page earlier, and I don't see anything about the debug mode specifically on that. Is it just extra logging output in watchdog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The debug mode is essential to test if your service is working correctly through posting the logs. You can see the logs in admin/reports/dblog.  These logs shows you if you are sending the appropiate format,  if there is any error, etc.  The logs  allow  you to see the output of the transactions. I have attached a image with some samples of the logs messages. As far as I understand that it is the only use for the debug mode in the services 3 modules. If it is not or this answer was not accquire please post a better explanation.

As you say it uses watchdog, so you can see internally what it is happening with your service. I have included the service code if you like to see the function yourself [git service](http://drupalcode.org/project/services.git/blob/bb4420148537c55f1cb064270b21f4e4389ed87d:/services.module#l245)

---

[image: service 3 logos].